# How can I use ARRAYFORMULA (or something similar) with GOOGLETRANSLATE?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate, google-translate

I'm learning a new language and I recently discovered Google Sheets' `GOOGLETRANSLATE` function. I thought it'd be neat to have a personal dictionary of translations which I can even annotate. So I created a simple sheet that translates words from column A in column B. So far so good.

The problem is I can't tell Google Sheets to "translate every cell in column A to column B". I used `ARRAYFORMULA` but it doesn't work as expected. `=ArrayFormula(GOOGLETRANSLATE(A2:A,"en","de"))` only results to

[image: only B2 is translated, not everything else]

As you can see, only B2 is translated, not everything else.

FWIW, dragging the fill handle down still works but I want an endless dictionary of such translations. I created the sheet on the web app but I use it primarily via the Android app. I want to just type the word in column A and get its translation. Unfortunately, if the fill handle even works in mobile, I don't know how to trigger it. (And I know this forum is for web apps so I'm going to stop right there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`ARRAYFORMULA`** does not support **`GOOGLETRANSLATE`**. The best you can have is to pre-program the array like this:

```
={GOOGLETRANSLATE(B20, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B21, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B22, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B23, "en", "de");
  GOOGLETRANSLATE(B24, "en", "de")}
```

[image: 0]

Another workaround would be to join stuff:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 GOOGLETRANSLATE(TEXTJOIN(". ", 1, B20:B24), "en", "de"), "."))))
```

[image: 0]

You may also resolve it via script or with API calls: **[https://developers.google.com/apps-script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app)**

Answer (score 4):

After analysis, I found kind of compact solution. a1:a, "en", "ko" are options
it doesn't need ARRAYFORMULA:

`=TransPose(Split(GoogleTranslate(Join(". ",A1:A), "en", "ko"),". ",false,false))`

Exception, if target lang is "ja", they need another way like this:
`=TransPose(Split(GoogleTranslate(Join(". ",A1:A), "en", "ja"),"。 ",true))`

Answer (score 0):

I have found @Sage's approach or any using GOOGLETRANSLATE(JOIN()) does *not* work well with Chinese. GOOGLETRANSLATE() seems to treat the JOIN() as a sentence no matter how meaningless it would be, and translates each character changeably according to the sentence.

What so far seems to give consistent results is

=MAP(*range*,LAMBDA(hanzi,GOOGLETRANSLATE(hanzi,"ZH","EN")))

Using a literal array {} for the LAMBDA result, you can return multiple values, such as Pinyin and translation.